# Sorting output of coauthors_wp_list_authors function - Co-Authors Plus plugin Wordpress

Tags: php, sorting, wordpress

The Co-Authors Plus plugin has a function called `coauthors_wp_list_authors()` that spits out a list of all the co-authors being used on the site. It accepts many of the same arguments as the standard wordpress function, [`wp_list_authors()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_authors).

Except it doesn't accept "order" or "orderby". ([here's a list of what it accepts](https://github.com/Automattic/Co-Authors-Plus/blob/master/template-tags.php#L394)). So without those arguments, **how can I customize the sort order of the authors?**

My usage is an "authors" page that lists every co-author on the site. The default sort seems to be the date that the co-author was created.

My function looks like this:

```
function display_authors() {
  $author_list = coauthors_wp_list_authors('number=500&echo=0');
  ?>
    <div class="author_list"><ul><?php return $author_list ?></ul></div>
  <?php
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Maybe you can use PHP to do the sorting. Here's a [similar question on the Wordpress Support forum](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/coauthors_wp_list_authors-sorting-and-positioning).

Comment: I'll try to figure that out. That was my question on the Wordpress forums. No one had answered it for two weeks, so I thought I'd try here. But someone answered it AS I was typing my question here!

Comment: Oh hah! Small world.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Funny. I am looking to do the same thing. I submitted a [pull request to the repo](https://github.com/Automattic/Co-Authors-Plus/pull/239) for the ability to filter the author array returned from get_terms. If this gets pulled, it'd be as simple as adding a filter on `coauthors_wp_list_authors_array` and filtering that array into the order that you want it. Until then...

--- UPDATE! (cue the Unsolved Mysteries update music) ---

OK so it looks like the pull request was merged and it was deployed to Automattic's [public SVN repo for VIP plugins](https://vip-svn.wordpress.com/plugins/co-authors-plus/template-tags.php) but they haven't updated the [.org plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/co-authors-plus/), so feel free to pester them to update it :-)

For prudence sake I will duplicate my response to your [wordpress.org forum thread](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/coauthors_wp_list_authors-sorting-and-positioning?replies=9#post-6351197) on how to use this filter to, for example, sort by display_name:

ok so, this is untested but *should* work. it also may not be the most efficient way of doing things.

This sorts by display_name if you want to sort by another property, change `display_name` to the property in the line

```
$sorted[$item->display_name][] = $item;
```

Note that both objects (the 'mock' user object and the WP_User object) must have the same properties for this to work, also note how the WP_User object uses the magic method __get().

```
function coauthor_sort( $authors ) {

    $sorted = array();

    foreach ($authors as $item) {
        $sorted[$item->display_name][] = $item;
    }

    uksort($sorted, "strnatcasecmp");
    $sorted_authors = array();

    foreach ($sorted as $subArray) {
        foreach ($subArray as $item)  {
            $sorted_authors[] = $item;
        }
    }

    return $sorted_authors;

}
add_filter('coauthors_wp_list_authors_array','coauthor_sort');
```

Comment: Looks like it was pulled in the git repo and added to VIP's plugin repo which was what I was looking for. Feel free to bug them to update the wordpress.org plugin if that's what you need :)